# About IIS Express' remote access one more time

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, iis-express

I can't understand where is my fault. Can anyone help me?? I have installed IIS Express 7.5 on windows XP, changed `binding` in `config` file, made `httpcfg` changes needed and run IIS but can't access to my site remotly. There are `config` file changes and `httpcfg query urlacl`

```
    <sites>
            <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
                <application path="/">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\WHCSP_install_with_instructions\WHCSP" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
            <siteDefaults>
                <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
                <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
            </siteDefaults>
            <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
            <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
    </sites>

C:\Program Files\Support Tools>httpcfg query urlacl
    URL : http://*:2869/
    ACL : D:(A;;GX;;;LS)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    URL : http://+:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/
    ACL : D:(A;;GX;;;WD)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    URL : http://+:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/
    ACL : D:(A;;GX;;;IU)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    URL : http://127.0.0.1:47873/help/
    ACL : D:(A;;GX;;;WD)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    URL : http://localhost:8080/
    ACL : D:(A;;GX;;;WD)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    URL : http://192.168.0.101:8080/
    ACL : D:(A;;GX;;;WD)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    URL : http://*:8080/
    ACL : D:(A;;GX;;;WD)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of port 8080 use normal port 80. Most likely your firewall does not have port 8080 open for inbound/outgoing connection.
Take a look at firewall configuration if you have access to it and make changes there for port 8080 if you bound to it..

And by the way did you configure DNS for your new site on your network or at least made entry in host file of the computer from which you attempt to gain access to that site?

Other possibility that something else already using your port in firewall and it is not IIS...